# UserControl Canvas.Left binding doesnt work

Tags: wpf, binding, canvas, user-controls

So the problem is this. I need UserControl which will have set Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left but these properties are binded from the ViewModel. For simplicity let's have this code for the user control with no code behind:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BadBinding.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}"
         >
 <Grid Width="100" Background="Red">
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="100" Maximum="250" />
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And this code for the main window:

```
<Window x:Class="BadBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BadBinding"
    >
  <Canvas>
    <local:MyUserControl />
  </Canvas>
</Window>
```

I don't know why is binding not working. When you set Canvas.Left directly to some value everything is fine as well as writing content of the user control directly to the main window.

Answer (score 2):

I think its because the `UserControl` is constructed befor being added to the `Canvas` and since `Canvas.Left` is an attached property it probably won't resolve correctly.

Try using a `Reference` binding.

```
<UserControl x:Class="BadBinding.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Canvas.Left="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=slider}, Path=Value}"
         >
 <Grid Width="100" Background="Red">
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="100" Maximum="250" />
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note: you may get a compile warning, but it will still compile.

But I think the best option would be to create a property on your usercontrol to bind the value, this will also work.

Comment: I will probably use this as a solution because I want no code behind. Still I would be happy if someone explained more deeply why this is not working.

Comment: I think its happening because even in Xaml the control is created then added to the container(Canvas) but because the Canvas.Left/Right properties are Attactched Properties the binding wont resolve when the UserControl is created as its not inside a Canvas at that point, if you applied the binding after the control has been added to the Canvas then it would work fine. I'm not sure if thats the correct explanation but from what I have seen over that last few years this is my best assumption.

Comment: Yep I agree with you but I'd like to know why it won't resolve and why it is done so (authors wanted that? it is not possible because of ...?). Just from the curiosity. It is worth to know the guts :)

Comment: You should ask this question at MSDN you may get a response as to why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot with `Bindings` but it dint worked for me too.. so if you wanna go with `EventHandler` then the following workaround may help you..

Remove the `Bindings` and add an event handler to `ValueChanged` event

In your ***MyUserControl.xaml***

```
<UserControl x:Class="BadBinding.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
 <Grid Width="100" Background="Red">
    <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="100" Maximum="250" ValueChanged="slider1_ValueChanged" />
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In your ***MyUserControl.xaml.cs***

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
     Canvas.SetLeft(this, slider1.Value);            
}
```

I tried this and working for me if you find any problem then let me know..

Comment: Thanks for answer but this should be View part of MVVM with no code behind so I rather use {x:Reference} and switch to this just in case Reference will stop working.